# How do I fix an imported model?

Tags: animation, rigging

[image]

I downloaded this Zelda 3D model last night and imported it into Blender. This is the model I choose to import:[image]

However when I imported the model I found an error in the model. There's large hole in the side of her waist, her left foot is inverted from the position of her body and both feet are sideways for some reason. I don't understand how fix the issue as I haven't used Blender to animate for anything before. Is it a rigging issue? Bone position? How do I fix this issue?[image]

Comment: hello, you've already asked your question and it lacked clarity, it's the same thing here, so please edit your original question, give some details and if it's possible share your file here: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)